# Seleccionar valores automaticos a partir de otro valor

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando seleccionar un valor en un campo, y que se carguen automaticamente otros dos valores en otros dos campos diferentes, pero no lo consigo.
La idea es que al seleccionar la CI se cargue el nombre y el apellido.

Dejo una imagen de referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo el codigo js que con el que he intentado realizar dicha accion en la view create.

```
@push ('scripts')
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bt_add').click(function(){
      agregar();
    });
  });


  $("#idpmed").change(mostrarValores);

  function mostrarValores()
  {
    cipaciente=document.getElementById('idpemed').value.split('_');
    $("#Primer_Apellido").val(cipaciente[2]);
    $("#Primer_Nombre").val(cipaciente[1]);    
  }


</script>
@endpush
```

Y aqui tambien estan los campos en la view create

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>C.I.</label>
                <select name="idpmed" class="form-control selectpicker" id="idpmed" data-live-search="true">
                    @foreach ($pacientesm as $pam)
                       <option value="{{$pam->idpmed}}_{{$pam->Primer_Nombre}}_{{$pam->Primer_Apellido}}">{{$pam->CI}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Primer_Nombre">Primer Nombre</label>
                 <input type="text" disabled name="Primer_Nombre" id="Primer_Nombre" class="form-control"placeholder="Primer Nombre">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="PApellido">Primer Apellido</label>
                 <input type="text" disabled name="Primer_Apellido" id="Primer_Apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que el id del select es `idpmed` y en el script buscas el id `idpemed`. Acostúmbrate a mirar la consola de javascript ya que da muchas pistas. En este caso la consola te debería estar dando algún error, que no puede leer la propiedad `value` de `null` seguramente.

Comment: No me di cuenta de ese error, de todas formas me sigue sin seleccionar los campos automaticamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He añadido un código simplificado con la corrección del id y funciona bien.¿tal vez es algún problema con la librería jquery? o ¿puede que los `value` del select no se estén cargando bien?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#idpmed").change(mostrarValores);

  function mostrarValores(){
      cipaciente=document.getElementById('idpmed').value.split('_');
      $("#Primer_Nombre").val(cipaciente[1]);   
      $("#Primer_Apellido").val(cipaciente[2]);
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>C.I.</label>
<select name="idpmed" id="idpmed">
    <option value="2_valor1_valor11">valor1</option>
    <option value="2_valor2_valor22">valor2</option>
    <option value="2_valor3_valor33">valor3</option>
</select>

<label for="Primer_Nombre">Primer Nombre</label>
<input type="text" disabled name="Primer_Nombre" id="Primer_Nombre">

<label for="Primer_Apellido">Primer Apellido</label>
<input type="text" disabled name="Primer_Apellido" id="Primer_Apellido" placeholder="Primer Apellido">
```

Comment: Acabo de probar guardando un registro y me selecciona los dos perfectamente justamente luego de guardarlos pero no me los muestra en el momento que selecciono el primer dato

Comment: Que raro, con el código que has puesto debería ir bien, tal vez ahí algo que impida que se lance el onchange del select. En la imagen que muestras, parece que el select esta deshabilitado y tiene un input debajo ¿es alguna clase de filtro? De ser así igual tiene que cambiar el evento o el elemento al que hace referencia

Comment: Si no logro encontrar la falla, porque me lo guarda bien y me lo muestra bien en la lista de registros principal. El select tiene un buscador integrado, no esta desabilitado.